# GAE and Urlfetch

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am on GAE 1.7.4 working with the urlfetch API....I tried do fetch via:

```
result=urlfetch(http://localdomain:8080/static/tabconfig.json)
```

I have opened opened up my static directory via a handler in app.yaml and download this json file via the browser.

But when I try do urlfetch in GAE it gives me a "Deadline exceeded error".  Does GAE restrict fetches from urls with the same domain?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why not just open the file?

Comment: If the SDK is not multithreaded it's waiting for the current request to finish before it can serve your json needed for your current request.

Comment: Hmmm..I have set threadsafe: true..I have a WAMP server in which I can URL reference a JSON file within the same domain without problems..I may have to do a file open or maybe host the JSON file in another domain (still learning this I guess)....thanks for the replys!

Comment: the problem is that the development server is single threaded, no matter if threadsafe is on. However, the GAE team is working on a new dev apserver, as they announced here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rEDCQtj4fo

Answer (score 2):

As tesdal already said in the comments, the development server is single threaded. That means that it can only handle one request at a time. So if you launch a request to a script, and that script urlfetches a page at your own server,, you're basically in a deadlock, because your original request is waiting for your urlfetch to return, while your urlfetched request is waiting, because the server is processing your original request.

The App Engine team is also working on an experimental new development server that is threaded, check out this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rEDCQtj4fo

If tesdal posts his comment as an answer, he was the first to post this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a deadline for a request, the most amount of time the service will wait for a response. By default, the deadline for a fetch is 5 seconds. The maximum deadline is 60 seconds for HTTP requests and 60 seconds for task queue and cron job requests.

```
result = urlfetch( url=http://localdomain:8080/static/tabconfig.json, deadline=60 )
```